# Is there an alternative for Dart's splitMapJoin in JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, dart, split, string-matching

I have a function in Dart which uses a regular expression to process matched and non-matched parts of the string differently.

```
Future<List<String>> _getQuestionParts(String questionText) async {
List<String> parts = List();

questionText.splitMapJoin(
  RegExp(r'&&[\s\S]*?\S##'),
  onNonMatch: (nonMatch) {
    nonMatch = nonMatch.trim();

    if (nonMatch.isNotEmpty) {
      parts.add(_texToLatex(nonMatch));
    }

    return nonMatch;
  },
  onMatch: (match) {
    String matchString = match.group(0);

    parts.add(matchString);

    return matchString;
  },
);

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  String part = parts[i];

  if (part.startsWith('&&') && part.endsWith('##')) {
    parts[i] = await _getBase64String(part, 'assets');
  }
}

return parts;
```

}

Sample text is -

> The total energy stored in the condenser system shown in the figure will be &&media/17.ELECTROSTATIC POTENTIAL AND CAPACITANCE_12.jpeg&&##media/17.ELECTROSTATIC POTENTIAL AND CAPACITANCE_12.txt##

Here, the two parts to be processed differently are -

1.

> The total energy stored in the condenser system shown in the figure will be

2. 

> &&media/17.ELECTROSTATIC POTENTIAL AND CAPACITANCE_12.jpeg&&##media/17.ELECTROSTATIC POTENTIAL AND CAPACITANCE_12.txt##

Is there a way to get this functionality in JavaScript ?

I think it would be a combination of split and match, but it should return the matched and non-matched parts in their correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by using a group (parentheses) while splitting -

```
var matches = text.split(/(&&[\s\S]+?&&##[\s\S]+?##)/gm);
```